# VBA Trigger 'ctrl'+'r'

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to refresh my PowerPoint presentation every 15 seconds, so that my presentation is always up to date, because it pulls data from a URL.

I'm trying to trigger Ctrl+r keys in a 15sec interval, in PowerPoint. Can anyone help me with the code?

Can I use this code? How can I add the function to trigger Ctrl and r?

```
Sub RunOnTime()
    dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)
    Application.OnTime dTime, "RunOnTime"    
End Sub

Sub CancelOnTime()
    Application.OnTime dTime, "RunOnTime", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to *achieve*, rather than what keyboard shortcut you're trying to use to achieve it.

Comment: I want to refresh my PowerPoint presentation every 15 seconds, so that my presentation is always up to date, because it pulls data from a URL.

Comment: Is there a Solution to automatically refresh Power Point every 15 seconds? Im very new in VBA coding and come to get help but no one can help in this topic :(

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys statement can be used with the following restrictions:

- SendKeys send characters to the active Window.
- Can not use Stop or breakpoint in the code.
- For these reasons, create a button on the ribbon to start the Sub, or insert in a running module.

With these insert in the code

```
SendKeys "^r"
```

Comment: According to the SO directives pls. post it as a new question.

Comment: Anybody idea? or can help?

Comment: There is no Application.Wait method in PowerPoint, for one thing, and for another, what's going to trigger this routine?

Comment: @Steve Pls. post your comment to the OP not in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Blackcat I'm responding to OP's question in the comment above, where he mentions Application.Wait.  He doesn't mention that in the original post, so referring to it there would only confuse things.